# C - fscanf works with characters pointers but not double character pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char **string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%s", *string); 

    printf("%s\n", *string);

}
```

This code generates a segmentation fault. However, if I change `**string` to be a single character pointer and change the `*string`s to `string` it works. Why is this? And how can I use fscanf with arrays of pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Short Answer: You are using malloc wrong

Comment: Do you want an array of strings? Like `string[0]` is a string, and `string[0][0]` is a char? You need to do a malloc for the array char** and then for each string char*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char **string = malloc(sizeof(char*)); // Pointer to pointer --> Alloc size of a POINTER
*string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20); // Dereference and then you can malloc chars
```

When you allocate a pointer to a pointer, you **allocate the size of the pointer** first. You then *dereference* the variable and allocate the size of the contents of the pointer, in this case, the number of characters that it points to.

Also, your usage of `fscanf` is not only unsafe, but totally unneccessary as well.

Use `fgets` instead:

```
fgets( *string, 20, fp );
```

If you want to allocate an array of pointers to chars, then multiply the sizeof char* by the number entries when allocating the pointer-to-pointer. You must also use a for loop to allocate memory for each character pointer as shown above.

```
// Example code
char **string = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 10); // Allocates an array of 10 character pointers
if (string == 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed.");
  exit(1);
}
int i = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
if (fp == 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open input.txt for reading.");
  exit(1);
}
for (; i < 10; ++i) {
  string[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20); // For each char pointer, allocates enough memory for 20 characters
  if (string[i] == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed.");
    exit(1);
  }
  fgets(string[i], 20, fp);
  printf("%s\n", string[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. I assumed allocating double pointers would just be the same as single pointers. The reason I'm using fscanf is that in my actual application (above code is just testing my error) I'm simultaneously scanning into three different double pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple `char *` pointer instead of double pointer:

```
char *string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
fscanf(fp, "%s", string); 

printf("%s\n", string);
```

Double pointer is pointer to a string (or array of strings), and the first pointer is not initialized anywhere in the original code. Additionally, the first `malloc` would have to look like `malloc(sizeof(char *)*20)` - that would give array of 20 strings (which would then need to be properly initialized in the loop)...

Also, not specifying the maximum size of the string is prone to buffer overflow errors, so worth looking at the limits, return values and things like that too.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for an array of strings, it's also possible to do a realloc for each time we want to add another string to the array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char **string = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 2); // array with 2 strings

    string[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%s", string[0]);
    fclose(fp); // Remember to close after you don't need file handle anymore
    printf("%s\n", string[1]);

    string[1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("input2.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fp2, "%s", string[1]); 
    fclose(fp2);
    printf("%s\n", string[1]);

    return 0;
}
```